# adding partitions dynamically in WebSphere JSR 352

Tags: websphere-liberty, jsr352

MY source table is having 10 records and I need to read 10 records and needs to process those and needs to write that processed records to the target table. For this 10 records I have created 2 partitions. But in my real project we don't know how many records daily i need to process so how can I decide that how many partitions do i need? 
Is it possible to add partitions dynamically?
Please find my poc code at [JSR 352 with Liberty Profile - how to implement checkpointing when ItemReader does a DB query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387625/jsr-352-with-liberty-profile-how-to-implement-checkpointing-when-itemreader-do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a PartitionMapper to dynamically define the number of partitions in a partitioned step.

This runs at the beginning of the step and builds a **PartitionPlan** which defines the number of partitions and the Properties for each partition.

In the XML, your **`<partition>`** element should include a child  **`<mapper>`** element rather than the child  **`<plan>`** element you'd use to define the number of partitions statically.

But you otherwise perform the substitution similarly using the **partitionPlan** property substitution.

E.g.

```
    <step id="mappedStep">
        <batchlet ref="MyBatchlet">
            <properties>
                <property name="xx" value="#{partitionPlan['xx']}" />
            </properties>
        </batchlet>
        <partition>
            <mapper ref="MyMapper">
                <properties>
                    <property name="mapperProp" value="#{jobProperties['mapperProp']}" />
                </properties>
            </mapper>
        </partition>
    </step>
```

Your PartitionMapper could build the **PartitionPlan** with something like this:

```
import javax.batch.api.partition.PartitionMapper;
import javax.batch.api.partition.PartitionPlan;
import javax.batch.api.partition.PartitionPlanImpl;

// ...
@Named("MyMapper")
public class MyPartitionMapper implements PartitionMapper {

    @Inject @BatchProperty
    String mapperProp;      // FROM JSL, USE IF YOU WANT, NOT USED HERE

    @Override
    public PartitionPlan mapPartitions() throws Exception {

        numPartitions = calculateNumPartitions() // YOUR LOGIC HERE

        Properties[] props = new Properties[numPartitions];

        Integer i;
         for (i = 0; i < numPartitions; i++) {
            props[i] = new Properties();
            props[i].setProperty("xx", "xxVal" + i);  // SUPPLY PER-PARTITION PROPERTY 'xx'
            props[i].setProperty("yy", "yyVal" + i);  // SUPPLY PER-PARTITION PROPERTY 'yy'
        }

        PartitionPlan partitionPlan = new PartitionPlanImpl();
        partitionPlan.setPartitions(numPartitions);
        partitionPlan.setPartitionProperties(props);
        partitionPlan.setPartitionsOverride(false);

        return partitionPlan;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Scott for your help.Actually I am not able to find any sample code to implement partition mapper. Can you please help me where can I find the sample.One more issue like i need to pass different parameters to each partition to fetch data as my source table is having timestamp only so that i need to pass 12AM to 6 PM timestamp rows into first partition and 6PM to 12AM partitions to another partition.

Comment: thank you for your quick help. I will try  this example.