# JSR 352. Restarting partitions : How to checkpoint the commits?

Tags: jsr352, java-batch

I have a partitioned job that reads from and writes to a DB. I have a chunking size of 100. If a partition fails and i want the restart to happen from the last commit, do i have to explicitly specify the checkpoint? (in Serializable checkpointInfo()?)

If so how/where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

You need to implement the pair of methods:  **checkpointInfo()** and **open()** for your **ItemReader** (and you can for your **ItemWriter** as well).

### Example

You can see an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387625/jsr-352-with-liberty-profile-how-to-implement-checkpointing-when-itemreader-do/37394239#37394239).

### More info

Note that for a partitioned step, each partition has its own checkpoint.   In this way the programming model is very similar from the reader/processor/writer perspective across partitioned and non-partitioned steps, and so they can be written independently of whether or not they are running in a partition (for the most part).